# Translation for error about use of tag "untagged"

Tags: bug, localization, untagged-questions, transifex

When trying to ask question with tag [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) there is an error with text:

> This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead.

> [image: warning about tag "untagged"]

However this text can't be translated, because it is missing in Transifex. Please add it.

Linked question on ruSO.meta: [Перевод предупреждения о запрете использовать метку untagged](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6508)

Answer (score 5):

The message for forbidden tags stored somewhere outside of transifex/traducir workflow, and can only be managed by the company's staff.

Recently on ruSO the tag [internet] [has been added to the list of forbidden entities](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13107/176217) and the text of notice

> [image]

has been discussed before between the site's moderators and @SpencerG as a company's representative. So all other such things should be handled on per-site-meta level.

Comment: Yep, the [tag:untagged] tag block is implemented as a separate block list entry on each site, which means there are [some sites that don't have the block yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352726/can-the-untagged-tag-be-blocked-on-the-newer-sites-too).