# Can the [untagged] tag be blocked on the newer sites too?

Tags: feature-request, tags, blocked-tags, untagged-questions

As per the details in [What is a blocked tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148#295149), the tag [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) is supposed to be blocked throughout the network. However, apparently the tag needs to be manually blocked for each new site separately, as indicated by [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122841/do-not-allow-users-to-tag-questions-with-untagged#comment986905_183008).

Currently, the following newly launched sites still don't have the block applied to the [untagged] tag. I checked by trying to ask a new question with just the [untagged] tag added, and noting that the tag is not caught by the question review process, unlike on other sites.

1. [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)
2. [EOS.IO](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/)
3. [Tezos](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/)
4. [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/)
5. [Drones and Model Aircraft](https://drones.stackexchange.com/)
6. [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)
7. [Proof Assistants](//proofassistants.stackexchange.com/)
8. [Substrate](//substrate.stackexchange.com/)

---

**Feature request:** Please block the [untagged] tag on the above sites as well, and possibly come up with a way to automatically block it on newly-created sites.