# Unable to translate the notice for "untagged" tag usage

Tags: bug, localization, untagged-questions

I just tried to add another tag to the [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533083/176217) tagged [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) and got an error message:

> [image: This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead]

I can't find that string in the translations DB via [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translation for error about use of tag "untagged"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304086/translation-for-error-about-use-of-tag-untagged)